# Send JFrame ImageIcon to the back of Frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm on the final part of my project and I'm having trouble sending my imported image "ship.png" to the back.

I have radio buttons set up inside of my class and I want to be able to see those radio buttons on top of ship.png that I imported.

Here's what I've tried so far but to no avail. The image that I import always seems to be in front of the radio buttons and/or getting rid of them all together.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Project2_ScottHogan
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    String path = "D:/CSCI_1301/Project2/ship.png";
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedImage shiplayout = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(shiplayout));

    JFrame main_frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Murracruise: The #1 cruise-line in the nation!"); //Sets a title for the JFrame
    main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Closes the JFrame when exiting

    Cabin_Choice choice = new Cabin_Choice("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.00); //Calls upon the constructor of my Cabin_Choice class
    main_frame.getContentPane().add(choice); //Places choice into the current JFrame pane
    main_frame.setContentPane(label);

    main_frame.pack(); //Sizes the frame
    main_frame.setVisible(true); //Allows us to see the frame





  } //Ends the main method
} //Ends the class
```

And here is where I set up the radio buttons inside my Cabin_Choice class:

```
description = new JLabel("Choose your Cabin or Suite"); //Creates the label
description.setFont(new Font("Helonia", Font.BOLD, 28)); //Changes the font to Helonia and boldens the text for description

cabin1 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-1");
cabin2 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-2");
cabin3 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-3");
cabin4 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-4");
cabin5 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-5");
cabin6 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-6");
cabin7 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-7");
cabin8 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-8");
cabin9 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-9");
cabin10 = new JRadioButton("Cabin 11-10");
suite1 = new JRadioButton("Suite 11-S1");
suite2 = new JRadioButton("Suite 11-S2");

cabin1.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin2.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin3.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin4.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin5.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin6.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin7.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin8.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin9.setForeground(Color.white);
cabin10.setForeground(Color.white);
suite1.setForeground(Color.white);
suite2.setForeground(Color.white);

cabin1.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202)); //This sets the background to my own custom color of blue
cabin2.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202)); 
cabin3.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin4.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin5.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin6.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin7.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin8.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin9.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
cabin10.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202));
suite1.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202)); //This sets the background for the suites to a custom purple color
suite2.setBackground(new Color(31, 21, 202)); //Custom purple color for the background of suite 2

//The following block of code puts the radio buttons into a group
//so that the user can only select 1 cabin or suite at a time
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(cabin1);
group.add(cabin2);
group.add(cabin3);
group.add(cabin4);
group.add(cabin5);
group.add(cabin6);
group.add(cabin7);
group.add(cabin8);
group.add(cabin9);
group.add(cabin10);
group.add(suite1);
group.add(suite2);

//
Cabin_Listener cabinlisten = new Cabin_Listener();
cabin1.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin2.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin3.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin4.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin5.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin6.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin7.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin8.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin9.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
cabin10.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
suite1.addActionListener(cabinlisten);
suite2.addActionListener(cabinlisten);

//
add(description);
add(cabin1);
add(cabin2);
add(cabin3);
add(cabin4);
add(cabin5);
add(cabin6);
add(cabin7);
add(cabin8);
add(cabin9);
add(cabin10);
add(suite1);
add(suite2);

//
setBackground(Color.white); //Sets the background for the entire frame
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,100)); //Sets the default size of the frame
```

Comment: Call `setContentPane` BEFORE you add anything to the frame.  Using `setContentPane` replaces the `contentPane` and anything that was added to it, with your new `contentPane`

Comment: I tried to move "main_frame.setContentPane(label)" right below "main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)" but the image is still blocking out my radio buttons. Could it be something to do with my class where I set the preferred size and background color?

Comment: Since I don't really have a runnable example, I'm just stated those things which are most obvious. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Call `setContent` before you add any new content to the frame
2. Set the `contentPane`'s layout manager (to something like `BorderLayout`), as `JLabel` doesn't have a layout manager set by default
3. Set `Cabin_Choice` to be transparent using something like `setOpaque(false)`, otherwise you won't see the background image

For example...

```
main_frame.setContentPane(label);
main_frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
main_frame.getContentPane().add(choice); //Places choice into the current JFrame pane
```

Also, [avoid using `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) in general, but in this case, it will have no effect as `JLabel` will ignore the values specified by it's child containers and only calculate the `preferredSize` based on the `icon` and `text` properties of the `JLabel` itself